# Remove a SubDirectory without knowing the Directory C#

Tags: c#

Quick question, I've listed all directories and subdir from a directory to a listbox but I need to remove a subdir from listbox.

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\root\\", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
```

My problem is I don't know the origin path

```
C:\\root\\UNKNOW\\path_to_remove_from_listbox\\
```

I know I need to do something like that:

```
listbox1.items.remove("C:\\root\\" + random param + "\\path_to_remove_from_listbox\\")
```

But don't know how

Comment: you have to iterate through your root directory until you find your subdirectory.

Comment: No, this is a public program, this need to be automatic, but if It's a another pc it will have different directorys, that I can find out the name, I only know the folder I need to remove from listbox

Comment: What is  the UNKNOWN?  Is it a known-to-Windows folder like Documents, Downloads,  Users > CURRENT-USER > AppData , ... ?  (Or is this for Android?)

Comment: it seems like you would just know the directory you want to remove. you won't even know the root directory, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about you filter them out prior to adding by using Linq?

```
string dirRoot = "C:\\root\\";
string dirNameToIgnore = "path_to_remove_from_listbox\\";
var dirList = Directory.GetDirectories(dirRoot, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                       .Where(s => s.StartsWith(dirRoot) 
                                    && !s.EndsWith(dirNameToIgnore))
                       .ToList();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(dirList);
```

What it basically does is finds dir paths with `GetDirectories` and selects only those that start with `dirRoot` and do not end with `dirNameToIgnore`.

Note that the strings that are returned by your `GetDirectories` might differ so adjust as needed.